# Check if multiple strings exists in list using Python

Tags: python

How can i test if multiple strings exist in another list? Below is a code example that I started with but doesn't work properly. It should return true if even part of the string is found in the list.

I marked in the comments what the result should return. as you can see they all fail though.

```
def all_exist(avalue, bvalue):
    if avalue == []:
        return True
    else:
        print (all(x in avalue for x in bvalue))

items = ['greg','krista','marie']
all_exist(['greg', 'krista'], items) # true
all_exist(['gre', 'kris'], items) # true
all_exist(['gre', 'purple'], items) # false
```

Would it be better to convert the second list to a single string and then just test if strings in list exist in it?

Comment: what is "even part of the string"? Do you mean any part of the string?

Comment: correct, so 'gre' shoud return true since the list of items contains 'greg'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to check if ***all*** of the strings in the first list is contained by ***any*** string in the second list:

```
def all_exist(avalue, bvalue):
    return all(any(x in y for y in bvalue) for x in avalue)

items = ['greg','krista','marie']
print(all_exist(['greg', 'krista'], items)) # -> True
print(all_exist(['gre', 'kris'], items))    # -> True
print(all_exist(['gre', 'purple'], items))  # -> False
print(all_exist([], items))                 # -> True
```

Comment: for the win!!! im making a search filter and this is how i would prefer it to work. thank you

Comment: If i understand it correctly, the: "any(x in y for y in bvalue) for x in avalue" part of that function is actually surrounded by extra "(" to create a generator. Which serves as the parameter for the all() function. But they are redundant to set here.

Answer (score 0):

We want to loop through the elements in `avalue` and check if this element is in any of the strings in `bvalue`. But we want to do all of that inside `all` as we want to check that `all` elements in `avalue` have a match.

Also, if we do the test this way, an empty `avalue` will return `True` anyway, so we don't need to tell Python to explicitly do this.

*Note that: since you have defined `all_exist` as a `function`, it should really `return` a value, not `print` the result, so I have changed that for you:*

```
def all_exist(avalue, bvalue):
    return all(any(i in j for j in bvalue) for i in avalue)
```

and some testing shows it works:

```
>>> all_exist(['greg', 'krista'], items) # true
True
>>> all_exist(['gre', 'kris'], items) # true
True
>>> all_exist(['gre', 'purple'], items) # false
False
```